# Same start and end date

Tags: custom-object, date

For a custom object, I have two date fields : `start date` and `end date`. I want to make sure the `end date` is greater than `start date`.

As per `https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_date.htm&type=5`, I created a validation rule `start date > end date` which would throw up an error saying `end date should be greater than start date`. And that works.

I'm confused why the validation rule does not show up when I set the `start` and `end` date to the same date.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you would like to also check if your Start Date and End Date are EQUAL, then you need to update your Validation Rule to check if they are **GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO** each other.

Example:

```
Start_Date__c >= End_Date__c
```

Comment: Thanks! Was thinking of my validation rule the wrong way